# Modifier with multiple keys syntax in AutoHotKey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to insert a Unicode character in AutoHotKey using the keyboard shortcut like
`'Alt-down' + a 9 'Alt-up'`
i.e. pressing the keys <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> while holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

I'm probably missing something (fairly) obvious but I can't find the syntax to to this.

Comment: Map which keys to send what unicode character? Explanation is a little confusing. - ie: I want to map **Ctrl C** to send **Alt,+,a, and 9** together. I tried Alt + a 9 and it sends a regular **o**, is that correct?

Comment: I was wanting to output various unicode characters using the codes given in charmap (e.g. U+00a9 for ©) which you can do using Alt_down numpad+ a 9 Alt_up (this needs a registry hack to work BTW). I guess the unicode stuff wasn't really central to the question, just the syntax for Alt_down, Alt_up. Sorry not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what key you're trying to map, the explanation is a little confusing, but this is the right side portion of the mapping:

```
Send {Alt Down}{+}{a}{9}{Alt Up}
```

although if you only want the Unicode character and now it's number (between 256 and 65535) you can use:

```
{ASC num_here}
```

Comment: That works great thanks. Was just this syntax I was after.